# Selenium leaves control after clicking to file explorer Browse button in MS Edge

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Selenium leaves control after clicking to file explorer Browse button in MS Edge. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but absolutely blocking to run next step in the code.  I tried code via all possible ways and below code works to click  to Browse button but after this step selenium leaves control because  file explorer window opens. Is this Selenium or MS Edge driver issue?

## Steps:

```
1. Open ajax web application through MS Edge (works)
2. Click to browse button through web driver core or java script method (works)
3. Selenium gone, leaves control till we close file explorer button (doesn't work) - this works fine in GC and FF.
4 (Blocked). Send key to type file name or implement AutoIt script (works)
5 (Blocked). Click to open button via AutoIt script (works)
6 (Blocked). File attached fine (works)
```

## Working code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("browseID")).click();
```

AND

```
WebElement we = null;
((JavascriptExecutor)ClientSessionFactory.session().webDriver()).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('browseName')[0].click()", we);
```

## Environment:

```
Selenium version - Latest 3.6.0
Browser - MS Edge
MS Edge Driver - Latest Release 15063
Application type - Ajax web
```

[image]

This is actually blocking attachment functionality and it would be great if selenium will fix this. So far i just see Autoit is the solution as a 3rd party software but it is very tedious to add separate scripts for every browse buttons in the application, any code by selenium blocks due to OS dialog appearance.

Comment: is the window open after click browse button is of browser means ie one or windows os one?

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4843

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. One solution can be to manipulate the "browse" window using an Auto-It script (for example). Right before click on the "browse" button, execute the Auto-It script and set a "sleep" command in the beginning to wait for 1-2 seconds. Now you can click on "browse" button. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. To fix it i pimped the AutoIt script using WinWaitActive() as a first directive to wait til window is active.
I run the script in a parallel process (subprocess.Popen in python) just before opening the file upload